# Changing hosting server to a website without having the certificate from the CA

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, hosting, cname-record, amazon-cloudfront

I have been helping a friend who published a wordpress webpage developed by a company he contacted that on production has a really poor performance, to fix this I created a react static web page which had a better performance and proposed to use the same domain with the react web page that is being used by the wordpress one, I don't have very much experience with this so the steps I have done to achieve it are the following:

- I created a amazon s3 bucket and configured it as a static webpage
- Created a Cloudfront distribution with the s3 website endpoint bucket as the origin

Now I need to update the DNS records on Godaddy where is the domain, for that I created a hosted zone on aws route53 but I didn't added the CNAME of the Godaddy domain to the cloudfront distribution because I don't have the ssl certificate, So if i don't do this I cant update the godaddy CNAME records, My question is, what can I do to get the ssl certificate? the company is unprofesional and does not want to give us the certificate, is there a way to generate a second certificate for the same domain? or a way to get again the old certificate?

Or am I doing something bad or understanding wrong the CNAME and DNS?

**EDIT:** We also don't have access to the current hosting server which is dreamhost.com

Comment: You can create a *new* certificate using Amazon's AWS Certificate Manager and apply it to the CloudFront distribution. They're free. It'll require you to create a few DNS records to validate your ownership of the domain.

Comment: ACM is the right answer for this. Just request a new certificate. Use DNS validation, create the DNS CNAME entries on GoDaddy (within DNS) and then assign the ACM certificate to CloudFront. As long as the DNS entries exist, the cert will renew automatically. Then transfer the DNS hosting to Route53 and the domain to a better registrar.